# Programmatically embedding picture in video

Tags: video, youtube, transcoding

I'm trying to figure out the best method to programmatically embed a logo onto videos uploaded from users before they are sent to a youtube channel. I'd like to do this with minimal artifacts added. The files will be uploaded to a server where I'll have both command-line and PHP access to it. It will be on a shared host, and I expect that the traffic won't be high to start.

My current thought is to use ffmpeg, however I wasn't sure how versatile that would be (with the tons of formats out there). I figured encode it at a high bitrate to minimize artifacts added and then upload to you tube.

Has anyone else programmatically had to get a logo onto youtube videos? What worked well for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg apparently has a [plugin for this](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC148).  However when I was looking into transcoding in general I decided it would be more fun to avoid all the arcane video permutations, and avoid the extra aggravation of dealing with long running processes.  So I decided to pipe my videos through a service.  [Encoding.com's API](http://www.encoding.com/api/category/category/complete_api_documentation#logo_fields) appears to support logos.